# Disneyland Paris - Super Fastpass availability

Tags: tickets, paris, disney

I've been trying to buy Super Fastpass from www.booktickets.disneylandparis.com but the whole of September is greyed out ("not eligible"). Does that mean those Fastpass tickets are not available in autumn/winter or that they'll probably become available later?

[image]

Comment: The booking calendar for September that I can see has three colours: MINI, MAGIC and SUPER MAGIC. The MINI is a light blue/grey colour.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I've updated the question with a screenshot. Did you navigate the website in the same way?

Comment: I could not get to your link but through [this](https://www.disneylandparis.com/en-gb/) athough it seems to arrive at the same place. Because of the note "FastPass gives limited access to some attractions but not to the parks" and because the One-Day access says "until 30th September" I had only looked at that, which has availability in September. Perhaps they have not yet marked up bookings for FastPass more than 3 months ahead, but apparently Disneyland is open.

Comment: Also, note that this page of [opening hours](https://www.disneylandparis.com/en-gb/calendars/park-hours/) shows that many attractions are temporarily closed. The calendar only goes to 3rd September.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for this additional info. I'm not keen on booking the trip (flights and hotel) if Super Fastpass isn't an option in September :( The closed attactions don't bother me since a number of them are closed now in June as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super FASTPASS for September became available at a later date.

I was able to purchase it yesterday. I guess the initial inavailability (in June) was due to the different price policy for September - weekdays are cheaper beginning with the second week of September so maybe the powers that be had to look into the demand first in order to know what to offer (at what prices).